# Using empty and raycast node in geometry nodes to shrinkwrap / debossed / control location of text on object

Tags: 3d-printing, geometry-nodes

Using empty and raycast node in geometry nodes to shrinkwrap / debossed / control location of text on object.

Example of debossed text.

[image: img1]

I know I can use mesh boolean and GN to create debossed text on an object See image below.

[image: img2]

I also can use the Raycast node to do the same thing.

[image: img3]

**But how can I use an empty (which controls the text location / position) to control the direction the raycast rays are coming from.**

Basically I'm trying to use an empty (which will control the text position) the text casts the rays onto an object which creates debossed text on **uneven / complex shaped objects wherever the empty is pointed.**

My thoughts were:

1. Create text and connect that with the raycast node to use text as the rays to cast onto object.
2. Extrude raycast text rays on object by 0.4 (so I can do a mesh boolean to create the debossed effect).
3. Connect empty to text so I can control the location of text rays hitting object (by just moving the empty)

I tried connecting the Object info node of the empty (**Location connector to Translation connector on the text object**) **but it just seems to hang.**

[image: img4]

Why am I doing this.  This would allow me to easily change the location that the text is coming from (to shrinkwrap text on odd shapes) by simply pointing an empty towards the location I want to deboss the text on.

**PS: this will be 3D printed so some thickness is needed to get the text to be indented /(debossed) using the mesh boolean node.**

**I'm using Blender 3.2.1**

Attached blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

do you mean like this?

[image]

by the vector subtraction: location empty from 50/0/0 (position of text) i got the direction.

So result:

[image]

Comment: Something like that, but something that allows the deboss to move all the way around (360 degrees) of the object. Wherever the empty is the deboss will take affect. Almost like parenting the empty to the text and wherever the empty is the deboss affects the object.